# Why my attribute values are implicitly cast to float in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am currently meet with a strange behavior.

Details:

In vertex shader, I declare the attribute at location 1 to be `uint`:

```c
layout (location = 1) in uint VS_In_ID
```

I declare it as `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` in C, stride 1:

```cpp
glVertexAttribFormat(1, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, 0);
```

I uploaded a bunch of unsigned int data correctly (I ensured this by calling `glGetBufferSubData`):

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.idsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint) * data.numPoints, data.ids, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindVertexBuffer(1, data.idsVBO, 0, sizeof(GLuint));
```

The attribute is rendered to a texture (binded at `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_1`) configured by

```c
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32UI, config.bufferWidth, config.bufferHeight, 0,
  GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
```

and the data is fetched by

```cpp
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSINGNED_INT, data);
```

but finally, I found the values I uploaded (all assigned '2') were implicitly converted to float, for example, when I fetch the value which should be 2, I got 0x40000000, which is a float 2!

This conclusion is not drawn after fetching, but in the shader using things like

```c
if (VS_In_ID == 0x40000000) 
    gl_Position.x = gl_Position.x + 1.0f;
```

and to see the displacement of the faces.

Why and when did this cast happen?

Comment: @JaMiT I updated the content.

Comment: I believe `glVertexAttribFormat` always produces floats. `glVertexAttribIFormat` is for integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why my attribute values are implicitly cast to float in OpenGL?

Because that is how it is specified. [`glVertexAttribFormat`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribFormat.xhtml) specifies how the data in the buffer is to be interpreted as floating point numbers, but `glVertexAttribIFormat` specifies how the data is to be interpreted as ints. This function specifies how the data for the shader program must be converted. As the type of vertex shader input cannot be guessed, there are different functions for different types. The *type* argument only specifies the type of the source data, but not the type of the target. So if the type of the attribute is `uint`, you have to use `glVertexAttribIFormat`.

<s>`glVertexAttribFormat(1, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, 0);`</s>

```cpp
glVertexAttribIFormat(1, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```